# CSS absolute background as link: active position

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I am creating image which has a link on top with. Image has been set as relative, and the link as absolute on the bottom of the image. Basically it is a link on top of the image with absolute position and fixed widh and height. On hover, background of the link changes it's color. The problem occurs whenever I click on the link: it goes top of the image (on Opera and IE it stays there). Images as examples:
In the picture below is a normal state of image with link (on hover background's transparency changes).
[image]

In this picture below is a state of `a:active` of the link.
[image]

It stays as absolute element, but changes it position. I have tried applying for `a:active` these options: copy everything from normal and hover states, `position:static;`, even tried to place a `margin-top` with a size that would be required to stay in bottom - no luck.

Here is the css code of it:

```
.image-with-link {width:300px; height:135px; position:relative; float:left; overflow:hidden;}
.image-with-link a {width:280px; height:18px; position:absolute; bottom:20px; left:0; padding:5px 10px; color:#fff; text-align:left; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); overflow:hidden;}
.image-with-link a:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

(link is no longer needed).

Comment: it would be easier to check this if you provide the link to the web page itself

Comment: Sounds like you have some CSS conflicting with the a:active declaration. As knightrider said, would be very helpful to see the actual page.

Comment: Edited and provided the link, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting CSS on lines 79 and 194 of custom.css that is overriding the absolute positioning:

You are declaring:

```
a:active, a:focus {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

and on line 194:

```
.kategorijos .vienas a:active {
    position:static;
}
```

Both of these are causing the problem. You want the item to keep `position:absolute` on :active.

Comment: Hi, what kind of software you are using to detect conflicts? Because I did not find anything relative to the links in line 79 of custom.css

Comment: I am just using Chrome's dev tools (right click on the thing and choose "inspect element"). You can then set the link to its active state and see what styles are being applied. You just need to make sure your CSS for the :active state overrides the less specific CSS. You can just add `!important` to the more specific CSS.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the source of what causes the problem, I found it on a different CSS file anyway. And since your answer came first, I will accept it.

Comment: You need really good reason to use !important. IMO this is not one.

Comment: @Saram generally I would agree. But the reason for that is so you don't overwrite things with it without thinking. !important by itself isn't necessarily *bad*. In this case, it shouldn't matter too much. Better would just be if he was more specific with his CSS classes, but in the end the result is the same.

Comment: @Saram unless I wanted to overwrite `top:1px` with command `!important` was not an option in this case. I fixed it by completely removing the source, at this point - `top:1px`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
a:active,
a:focus{
    /* Give clicked links a depressed effect. */
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

You overwrite `position`, but not `top` in following selector: `.kategorijos .vienas a`. You should add `top: initial` for fix.
I assume that `position: static` is by design here:

```
.kategorijos .vienas a:active {position:static;background: url('../images/arrow.png') 270px 4px  no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

This moves link below image.

Comment: Thank you, for explaining what I did and did not overwrite. Just out of curiosity, shouldn't `bottom:0 !important;` overwrite `top`?

Comment: This is not possible to overwrite one property by other. Browser applies both, and your element is higher, but content is top aligned - so it goes up. Try `vertical-align:bottom` (I did not test it). IMO overwrite `top` by `top: initial` is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**, I guess this will work :)

```
a:active, a:focus {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.kategorijos .vienas a:active {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: `position:static;` did not solve the problem for Opera and IE, only for Chrome at that matter.